# Django select field without defining choices

Tags: django

How do I create a form select field in Django without defining the choices in it? I'm using {{ myform.field }} in my template.

As far as I understand it's the choices attribute that renders the field as a select in django forms:

```
CHOICE_1 = "choice1"
CHOICE_2 = "choice2"

MY_CHOICES = (
(CHOICE_1 = "1"),
(CHOICE_2 = "2"),
)

field = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MY_CHOICES, defaults="1")
```

But I don't want to define my choices here, I want to add them in jQuery because the value list depends on the contents of another field. And I want this to change dynamically.

1) How do I get my template tag {{ myform.field }} to render as a select without choices?

**OR**

2) If you define your choice list, will django allow you to save other values that aren't in the list or will this raise a validation error? This way I can use a 'default' choice list that I change later.

Comment: 1) You can always just create your select input field in HTML/jquery and process/validate the posted data in your django view, you don't have to use `{{myform.field}}`. Just make sure you set the id and name attributes properly so it gets posted correctly. 2) Yes, you'd get a validation error if you input something that's not in your choices.

Comment: You can make a new table with the choices and have a foreign key access that table and use queryset.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks I'll do it that way. I'll just create it in jQuery, I don't know why I didn't just do that in the first place!

Comment: have you tried supplying the choices with an empty list? `[]`? or `(('','-Select one'))` which you can remove or keep with jQuery easily.